# Sentiment Analysis with Naive Bayes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do sentiment analysis on tweets in R, using Naive Bayes classifier. The tweets have been manually tagged as either positive or negative. The packages I'm using are: tm, weka, RTextTools, e1071. The problem is when I run the code, it seems that all tweets are predicted as positive, as shown in the confusion matrix,so I think there is something wrong in my Document Term Matrix, or I'm missing something else all together.
I think the main problem may be the very sparse Document Term Matrix, which maybe causes problems for the NB classifier, for this is what I get:

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 2289, terms: 8565)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 20052/19585233
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 73
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I'm also trying to figure out how the reduce the amount of sparse entries, and reduce the sparsity percentage from 100% to around 50-70%.

I used an example from http://chengjun.github.io/en/2014/04/sentiment-analysis-with-machine-learning-in-R/ , and tried to apply the solution shown there into mine problem.

```
file <- read.csv("twitter4242_2_1a.csv") #the file has two columns, the first stating
#stating positive or negative, and the second column has the tweets text itself
tweetsCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(file[,2])) # selecting the tweets from the 2nd column
tweetsTDM <- DocumentTermMatrix(tweetsCorpus,
    control = list(
    asPlain = TRUE,
    stopwords = TRUE,
    tolower = TRUE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE,
    stemWords = FALSE,
    removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stripWhitespace = TRUE))
    #tokenize = NGramTokenizer)) I'm not sure if the tokenizer should be included or not, but I get the same result regardless.

mat1 <- as.matrix(tweetsTDM) # creating matrix from the tweetsTDM
classifier <- naiveBayes(mat1[1:1500,], as.factor(file[1:1500,1])) # training the NB classifier with the first 1500 rows, with the factor from the first column (positive/negative)
predicted <- predict(classifier, file[1501:2288,]); #predicting the remaining rows in file, based on the classifier model
table (file[1501:2288,1], predicted) # confusion matrix
```

example of result I get:

```
    predicted
        negative positive
negative      0       324
positive      0       464
```

Comment: Take a guess as your example is not reproducible: does `mat1[1:1500,]` columns need to be factor's as well in your `naiveBayes` call and should you remove the first column `mat1[1:1500,]` to `mat1[1:1500,-1]`. And also from from `file[1501:2288,]` in your predict call - `predict(classifier, file[1501:2288,-1])` - otherwise your are using the class variable to predict itself. (should it be`file` or `mat` in predict)

Comment: You might also want to check out the threshold option. I wish I had a better idea what it did, but by playing with it, you can achieve more negative predictions.

Comment: @user20650: the column in mat1[1:1500,] doesn't need to be factor in the naiveBayes classifier, and removing the first column as per your suggestions, didn't make a difference. The main problem I think is the sparsity of the TDM, and I don't know who to reduce it.